# Selenium WebDriver JAVA a loop or other way to get results

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

If you want to solve the question, when you want, one should write out the pesel numbers on the form screen.

My code looks like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("pesel"));
element.sendKeys("74091943656");
```

Comment: My english is maybe bad, but I don't understand your question. What do you need to achieve?

Comment: I would like to add different data to my form, which is in the loop after every start of the driver.
For example: 88010901, 827272,28272
driver.findElement (By.id "pesel"). sendKeys (88010901, 827272,28272)

Comment: 1 start + loop all values? or 1 value per start?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I would like each of these loops to be added one by one to the form

Comment: help in down my

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop:

```
String[] values = {"88010901", "827272", "28272"};

    for (String value: values) {

        // code for loading the form

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("pesel"));
        element.sendKeys(value);

        // continue with saving the form?
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check it out soon :)

Comment: I would like each of these loops to be added one by one to the form

Comment: A request for help in this loop, I use selenium and I want to make this data in the loop, in this case the pesel, behind each open program, a different pesel was substituted (one by one or random) for the time being the first one is always substituted.